# filter posts based on a particular field in django template

Tags: python, django

I am working on a django application. The application holds a form which when filled will redirect to **item_list** page where the user can view the item they posted and also delete the item. I want this page to list only the items posted by that particular user who is currently logged in. but right now, this page lists items by every user. I tried adding an if case to the template but this results in displaying none of the posts. what am I doing wrong? this is my code so far

**items_list template**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %} items {% endblock title %}

{% block header %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/item_list.css' %}">

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/item_list.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock header %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <center><h2>Items</h2></center>
  <table class='table table-borderless table-hover'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Image</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Pattern</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Vendor</th>
        <th>Upload date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    {% for item in items %}
      {% if request.user == item.vendor %}
      <tr>
        <td>
          <a href="{{item.img.url}}" target="_blank"><img src="{{item.img.url}}" alt="{{item.title}}" style="width:80px;"></a>
        </td>
        <td>{{item.title}}</td>
        <td>{{item.pattern}}</td>
        <td>{{item.color}}</td>
        <td>{{item.vendor}}</td>
        <td>{{item.date}}</td>
        <td>{{item.time}}</td>
        {% endif %}
        <td>
          <a href="{% url 'upload_item' %}" class='btn btn-outline-warning btn-sm text-dark' style="width:100px">Edit item</a>
        </td>
        <td>

          <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" style="width:100px">Delete item</button>

          <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="card-header"><center><h5 class="modal-title">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</h5></center></div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="height:200px">
                  <center>
                    <br>
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'delete_item' item.pk %}" style="margin-top:10%;">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                      <button type='submit' class="btn btn-danger" style="width:200px">Delete item</button>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal" style="width:200px">Cancel</button>
                    </form>
                  </center>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                  <center>Once an item is deleted, It cannot be retrieved</center>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </td>
```

I am trying to filter the items based on `request.user` and `item.vendor`. But this displays none of the items.

**views.py**

```
def upload_item(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_des = ItemForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form_des.is_valid():
            form_des.save()
            return redirect('item_list')
    else:
        form_des = ItemForm()
        form_des.fields['vendor'].widget.attrs['value'] = request.user
        form_des.fields['vendor'].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

        return render(request, 'upload_item.html', {'form_des': form_des})

def item_list(request):
    items = Item.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'item_list.html', {'items':items})
```

under upload_item function in views.py, I have made the vendor field readonly and autofilled to the user posting the item so that it cannot be changed.

What am I doing wrong? Please help me

Thank you

Comment: post the view from which you are passing the data to template

Comment: Are you using any Django ORM? You could query your database filtering by the request.user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do the filtering in your view:

```
def item_list(request):
    items = Item.objects.filter(vendor=request.user)
    return render(request, 'item_list.html', {'items':items})
```

Comment: thanks. This worked. I have just another doubt. There is  another type of user **merchant**. This merchant should be able to see posts by all vendors. How do I do that. Right now when logged in as a merchant, the item_list template does not show any posts

Comment: Just use an `if` statement to check if `request.user` is a merchant or not, and set `items` accordingly.